# How can i make Ant design subMenu stay open in React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

Im using **Ant Designs(version 3.3)** subMenu component.
And after im clicking on a link inside of that sub menu, the sub menu collapses(see images).
How can i make it so it remains open?

```
const Menu = () => {

return (
   <Menu
      defaultSelectedKeys="start"
      defaultOpenKeys="start"
      mode="inline"      
    >
    <SubMenu
        key="admin"
        title={
          <span>
            <span>Admin</span>
          </span>
        }
      >
          <Menu.Item key="setup">
            <Link href="/setup/[programId]" as={`/setup/${programId}`}>
              <a>Program</a>
            </Link>
          </Menu.Item>
      </SubMenu>
    </Menu>
)}
```

I tried by adding a useState hook but its not working. But if put a string directly in to the openKeys prop it works but its ofc static.

```
const Menu = () => {
  const [openTab, setOpenTab] = useState("");
 const onOpenKeysChange = (props) => {
    setOpenTab(props);
  };

  return (
   <Menu
      defaultSelectedKeys="start"
      defaultOpenKeys="start"
      mode="inline"
      onOpenChange={onOpenKeysChange}

      // Not working
      openKeys={openTab}
      // Works static
      openKeys="setup"
    >
   <SubMenu
        key="admin"
        title={
          <span>
            <span>Admin</span>
          </span>
        }
      >
          <Menu.Item key="setup">
            <Link href="/setup/[programId]" as={`/setup/${programId}`}>
              <a>Program</a>
            </Link>
          </Menu.Item>
      </SubMenu>
    </Menu> 
)}
```

[image: Menu opened, link not clicked]

[image: Link clicked, menu closed]

Comment: Did you see the official example? https://codesandbox.io/s/vxjfp
sub menu won't collapse after click, in that example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide `onOpenKeysChange` with a parameter try `onOpenKeysChange("static")` for example

Comment: I already get props for onOpenKeysChange. If i add parameter there im getting to many renders of the hook and internal 500

Comment: Then try to add it here like an arrow function onOpenChange={()=>onOpenKeysChange}